# Flame Sensor with the Pi

Tags: raspbian

I have connected the Flame Sensor with the Raspberry Pi,

This is my connections,

Flame Sensor has 3pins, VCC, Ground and D0 (Digital Output).

VCC is connected to 5 volts (the range is 3.3Volts to 5volts)
GND is connected to the Ground.
and D0 is connected to the GPIO4.

A resistor is connected between the signal pin and the ground.

The output is either 1 or a 0.

Here is my code for the sensor Flame detection,

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN)
input = GPIO.input(7)
while True:
  if (GPIO.input(7)):
    print("Flame Detected")
  else:
    print("Not Detected")
```

I want to know if I write the code correctly ?
Because, even if I put the Flame sensor close to the Flame it still gives the output as "Not Detected".

It is the link for the Sensor Datasheet,
http://www.fut-electronics.com/wp-content/plugins/fe_downloads/Uploads/Flame-sensor-arduino.pdf

Answer (score 6):

You said you are using GPIO4, you are reading GPIO7.
The code should read:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN)
input = GPIO.input(4)
while True:
  if (GPIO.input(4)):
    print("Flame Detected")
  else:
    print("Not Detected")
```

Also Vcc should probably be connected to 3.3v, otherwise D0 may push 5v into the GPIO, which is not 5v tollerant!

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with Flame sensor with 4 leg which is A0 & D0 it will not gives you output from above code...
for reading these values it may be use ADS.